# Measurable set in the product measure

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure space and $f \in L^(X)$ where $f$ is positive. Let $$G_f = \{ (x,y) \in X \times [0, \infty]: y \le f(x) \}$$

Show that $G_f$ is $\mathcal{M} \times \mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}}$ measurable.

$\textbf{My Attempt + Question}$

It looks that $G_f:= X \times [0, f(x)]$. Given that $X \in \mathcal{M}$ and $[0, f(x)] \in \mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}}$, since $[0, f(x)]$ will be closed. Shouldn't this be enough to conclude $G_f$ is measurable?

The book gives the hint that the map $(x,y) \to f(x)-y$ is the composition of $(x,y) \to (f(x),y)$ and $(z,y) \to z -y$.

What am I missing in the conclusion of my above statement? I am assuming that the hint would be necessary but I don't see how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It looks that $G_f:=X\times [0,f(x)]$.

No.  What is $x$?

---

Note that measurability of $G_f$ would follow from measurability of the map $(x,y)\mapsto f(x)-y$ from $X\times \mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$.  You can show that this map is measurable using measurability of $f$ and continuity of subtraction, along with the decomposition of the map as described in the hint.

Comment: It is not completely obvious to me that the inverse image of $f(x)-y$ would be $G_f$. How did you see this?

Comment: "the inverse image of $f(x)-y$...."  It isn't clear what you mean here.  Given a function $g:A\to B$ and a subset $C$ of its codomain, you can find an inverse image of $C$ under $g$, $g^{-1}(C) = \{a\in A: g(a)\in C\}$.  If your function is $g(x,y)=f(x)-y$, what is $C\subset \mathbb R$ to make it so that $g^{-1}(C) = G_f$?

Comment: @JonasMeyer Isn't map from $\mathbf{X}\times \bar{\mathbb{R}}\to \bar{\mathbb{R}}$?