# if $f \geq 0$ Lebesgue measurable the set $A := \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid 0 < y < f(x)\}$ is measurable - proof verification

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, measurable-sets

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^+$ be a positive, Lebesgue measurable function.
Denote the set $A := \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid 0 < y < f(x)\}$ . 
Show that $A$ is Lebesgue measurable.

Is the following correct?

$\textbf{My attempt:}$

we can write that there exists a rational $r$ that $f(x)-y >r>0$ so $f(x)>r+y>0$

$$A = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid f(x) - y>0 \} = \bigcup_{r\in\mathbb{Q} \\ r >0} \bigg[ \bigg( \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 \mid f(x)>r\}\times \mathbb{R}\bigg)\cap  \bigg( \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 \mid y>-r\}\times \mathbb{R}\bigg) \bigg]$$

Comment: Definitely can't be right because you're taking subsets of $ \mathbb{R}^2 $ cartesian product with $ \mathbb{R} $, which means you're ending up with subsets of $ \mathbb{R}^3 $ in your union, which is definitely not what you want.

Comment: Another reason you can't be right is that you no-where used the measurability of $ f $.  Edit: okay, this is wrong because you're implicitly using the measurability of $ f $ when you define sets where $ f(x) > r $.  You're more just having notation issues.

Comment: You're pretty close.  Your sets, I'm pretty sure, should be something along the lines of $ \{ x \in \mathbb{R} | f(x) < r \} \times (0,r) $.

Comment: Also, your second set (with the $ y > -r $ clause) is pretty silly because it permits negative values of $ y $, which isn't useful because the set you're trying to construct only has positive values of $ y $.

Comment: you get the right idea using the separability of $\Bbb R^2$ however at this point the proof is not right, you need to fix the notation

Comment: Similar to the exercise 2.5.50 of Folland's textbook. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1045702/measurable-set-in-the-product-measure?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write
$$\{ 0 < y < f(x)\} = \{y>0\}\cap\{f(x)-y>0\} = \{y>0\}\cap P^{-1}(0,\infty)$$
where $$P:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R , \quad P(x,y) = f(x) - y.$$
$P$ is  measurable, so the result follows.

Closer to your attempt (along the lines of Jake's comments)- For $q\in\mathbb Q_+$, let $$A_q = B_q \times (0,q), \quad B_q = \{x\in\mathbb R : 0 < q < f(x)\}.$$
For $x\in B_q$, we have $f(x)>q$, i.e. $(x,q)\in A$. Thus $A_q \subset A$. Therefore $\bigcup_q A_q\subset A$.

For $(x,y)\in A$, we have $(x,r)\in A$ for some rational $0<y<r<f(x)$, and $x\in B_r$. Thus $(x,y)\in A_r \subset \bigcup_q A_q, $ and therefore $A \subset \bigcup_q A_q$. In conclusion:
$$A = \bigcup_{q\in\mathbb Q_+} A_q.$$

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try the hint of Folland's textbook which is considering
the map $(x,y) \to f(x)-y$ is the composition of $(x,y) \to (f(x),y)$ and $(z,y) \to z -y$. It is suffices to show all maps are measurable.